# jquery trigger on('click') of dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a webpage that uses an image map. The image and map are loaded dynamically. If I click on the area element new content is loaded. Also the url changes its hash (eg. index.php#somepage). I have three layers of pages, the main layer (homepage) has it's own image with a map (index.php), the second layer offers a new image + map (index.php#somepage) and the third layer opens an overlay on the second layer, therefore changing the hash (index.php#somepage_somesubpage).

I now want to be able to send someone a link to index.php#somepage_somesubpage. So I slice the hash and trigger the click-method of the imagemap on the first level to load index.php#somepage when the page is loaded. I added a callback to that, calling the desired click-method of the now updated imagemap. This does not work for some reason I can't figure out. I am able to open index.php#somepage, but when I enter index.php#somepage_somesubpage I end up getting the same result.

Here is the code of $(document).ready:

```
var cont = $('#content');

$( document ).ready(function() {
    cont.load('pages/home.php', function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
        if(statusTxt=='error')
        {
            cont.load('404.php');
        }
        lineparser('#content'); //Perform some fancy stuff on the page

        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');

        if (hash != ''){
            if(hash.indexOf('_') > 0)
            {
                //open page with content

                $('area[href~="#' + hash.slice(0, hash.indexOf('_')) + '"]').first().trigger("click", function(){
                    $('area[href~="#' + hash + '"]').first().trigger("click");
                });
            }
            else{
                //open menu page

                $('area[href~="#' + hash + '"]').first().trigger("click");
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: trigger() jquery method doesn't accept any callback as second parameter, only an object or an array of extra data to pass to the event handler http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: So, could I use .click() ? If not, seeing that simply putting the lines after each other does not help, what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

```
$('area[href~="#' + hash.slice(0, hash.indexOf('_')) + '"]').first().trigger("click", [hash]);
```

Then I added the following:

```
$(document.body).on('click', "map area", function(e, schachteln){
    ...
    if(schachteln){
        $('area[href~="#' + schachteln + '"]').first().trigger("click");
    }
}
```